# Why aren't ELL, Writers, etc available as "migration" options when flagging/closing posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why is it that I can close a question as "*better suited to Meta*", but not as "*better suited to ELL*" or "*better suited to Writers.SE*"?

[image: screenshot of all available migration targets when closing a question, which only lists meta.english.SE]

Should we add (at least) ELL and Writers to the list of available migration targets for flagging and closing?

Comment: Related: *[Proposal to fix the uselessness of the new off-topic close options](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4021)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only mods can recommend migration to a site that is still in beta, presumably because the scope of the site is still being defined.  This has come up frequently all across the network, but I do not think there is any chance of changing it.

Comment: ELL and Writers are still in beta? Maybe feeding them some more questions from ELU would help them.

Comment: @Mitch; actually, Writers has gone *back* to beta; perhaps they need more experts.